# ActiveRecord :select is messing with my data types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have this very simple snippet.

```
Topic.all(:select => 'count(*) as cnt')[0].cnt   # behaves the same on all models
"500"  # What, a string?
```

It seems that for some reason ActiveRecord is coercing the count to a string. In fact, I notice it coerces everything in the select list missing from the original object to a string.

Why does this happen?

What is a monkey patch to fix this so it works as expected?

**Please**: I do not want to use Topic.count, I have some tricky grouping and selecting I need to do.

FYI using ActiveRecord 2.3.5

Proof that the info is in the raw connection:

```
ree-1.8.7-2009.10 > r = ActiveRecord::Base::connection.raw_connection.query(
     "select 1").fetch_field.type == Mysql::Field::TYPE_LONGLONG
 => true
ree-1.8.7-2009.10 > r = ActiveRecord::Base::connection.raw_connection.query(
    "select 'a'").fetch_field.type == Mysql::Field::TYPE_VAR_STRING
 => true
```

And when using the Stmt APIs you get stuff with the right types back automatically

```
ree-1.8.7-2009.10 > s = ActiveRecord::Base::connection.raw_connection.stmt_init
 => #<Mysql::Stmt:0xbd083dc>
ree-1.8.7-2009.10 > s.prepare("select 1, 'hello'")
 => #<Mysql::Stmt:0xbd083dc>
ree-1.8.7-2009.10 > s.execute
 => #<Mysql::Stmt:0xbd083dc>
ree-1.8.7-2009.10 > s.fetch
 => [1, "hello"]
ree-1.8.7-2009.10 >
```

But ... the Active Record MySql Adapter uses the query API that returns strings.

```
ree-1.8.7-2009.10 > cnn.query("select 1,2,3 union all select 1,2,3").each{|r| p r}
["1", "2", "3"]
["1", "2", "3"]
```

Comment: You must have some reason for not simply tacking '.to_i' on the end, right?

Comment: I can work around the issue, but Im trying to find the root cause, my gut tells me its cause the abstract adapter defines no way to do these kind of things

Comment: "Please: I do not want to use Topic.count, I have some tricky grouping and selecting I need to do." Which is why they invented count_by_sql ...

Comment: count_by_sql only returns a single value, I need multiple counts one per row

Answer (score 0):

It might actually be because there is no easy way to assume what the value is, so String is 'safe'. Anything in a select that does not map to a column can't be introspected for a type.

Comment: Its available in the MySql::Result object ... its just that when it auto generates the dynamic method, it does not pull it out of there ... probably cause its not defined in the interface ...

Answer (score -1):

The problem is MySQL.  When MySQL returns the result set, the result set does not have information as to what types are the columns.  ActiveRecord can only do the best it can: treat everything as a String.

ActiveRecord can treat columns coming back from a "normal" query (SELECT id FROM topics) as the correct type because ActiveRecord asked the DB for the types of the columns.

Comment: This is just not true. You have the same type of problem when quering DB2 on an AS/400. Make a join, select from the joined table and you receive a string. It's ActiveRecord that is mangling the data.